# Can I use JQuery position() of the element relative to silbling's child?

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, position

Based on jQuery documentation there are two methods that return element's position: offset() and position(). Offset gives me position relative to window screen, while position() relative to parent element.

What I'm after is to get the position of `<div class="main_element">` relative to `<div class="SILBLINGS_CHILD">`:

```
<div class="main_element"></div>
<div class="silbling"></div>
<div class="silbling">
    <div class="SILBLINGS_CHILD"></div>
</div>
```

The reason is that I'm doing fixed positioning on the scrollable div (and so when I scroll the main div down, main_element won't be visible but should maintain it's fixed position).

How can that be achieved?

Comment: *`"Offset gives me position relative to window screen"`* that's not true, should give you the coord. relative to the `document`

Comment: Why not use some CSS to keep it fixed?

Comment: `document`? Now you're splitting hair, `document` doesn't take under consideration elements that are outside the window screen, at least based on my quick checkout (`$(window).height()` gave me exactly same number as `$(document).height()`). I'm after getting coordinates relative to the silbling>child element outside the screen, never mind exact definition.

Comment: Jean-Paul - it is css fixed, but now the screen scrolls and element need to scroll out of the screen together with the silbling>child object (in other words fixed position `top:` dimensions need to be adjusted dynamically by jQuery)

Answer (score 0):

code will be `$('.SILBLINGS_CHILD').parent().prev().prev()`.

Test with `alert($('.SILBLINGS_CHILD').parent().prev().prev().attr('class'));`

You can then get the coordinates with code: `$('.SILBLINGS_CHILD').parent().prev().prev().offset()`.

```
var left = $('.SILBLINGS_CHILD').offset().left - $('.SILBLINGS_CHILD').parent().prev().prev().offset().left;
var top = $('.SILBLINGS_CHILD').offset().top - $('.SILBLINGS_CHILD').parent().prev().prev().offset().top;
```

The idea is to subtract the offset of the "nephew"(`.SILBLINGS_CHILD`) from the offset of `.main_element`